# Find location of program in Aix/Unix not in $PATH variable

Tags: unix, aix

I am very new to using Aix/Unix and trying to figure out some basics. Right now when I type

```
$ private_build <some options>
```

into the terminal, it begins running a program (private_build) my company has written. I'd like to know how the OS knows where to find this program to execute it. I know that it typically searches through all the directories listed in the $PATH environment variable. However, I've searched through each directory listed in $PATH carefully and cannot find a file of this name anywhere. I also tried:

```
$ which private_build
```

and

```
$ whereis private_build
```

but neither could find it (I think these commands just look through $PATH as well).

Is there another way Aix or Unix finds commands/programs entered into the terminal? I know we have networked drives mounted onto this machine, is it possible that if the program is on a mounted directory it would not be in $PATH? Do I need the file type extension (.exe? .ksh?) on the end?

Comment: Possibly an "alias". See if `alias private_build` tells you anything. (Aliases would be set in your login "profile".)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I found the answer: 'private_build' was an alias for a path to the actual executable. If you're having a similar problem, just use the command:

```
$ alias
```

to print out all aliases on your OS.

Comment: The $ is the prompt, not part of the command (perhaps remove it to avoid confusion).

Comment: Thanks, added a space to make it clearer that the command is intended for the command prompt, but the $ is not a part of the command